# Update static object constantly in a thread and using in others activities

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a static object in a class.

```
public class AppHelper {
    public static MyObject CONSTANT_ = new MyObject();
}

// and my object
public class MyObject {
    private Integer status;
    // get and set for status
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    // oncreate()
    // onresume()
    public void OnUpdate() {
        if (AppHelper.CONSTANT_.getStatus == 1) {
            // doStuff
        } else if (AppHelper.CONSTANT_.getStatus == 2) {
            // doOtherStuff
        }
    }
}

public class MyService extends Service {
    // oncreate()
    public void callServer() {
       // implementation of thread ommited
       Endpoint.get(URL, new CallBack(Response response) {
           AppHelper.CONSTANT_ = jsonToObj(reponse); // method for conversion is Ok
       });
    }
}
```

And activities have to call `AppHelper.CONSTANT_.getStatus()` for show a different view. My thread updates `CONSTANT_` object constantly.
So, sometimes I use something like this:

```
MyObject obj = AppHelper.CONSTANT_;
```

When I set any field in `obj`, few seconds later the setted field come back to empty. Is `obj` linked with `AppHelper.CONSTANT_` ? If so, have some other way to supply this `status` field without have a constant?

Comment: Please add the code where you set and get the values of that field

Comment: You could use an event bus (greenrobot's EventBus, `LocalBroadcastManager`, something based on RxJava/RxAndroid, `MutableLiveData`, etc.), to send out status updates to interested parties.

Comment: "My thread updates CONSTANT_ object constantly" Do you mean you assign a new value `CONSTANT_ = ...`? Or that you change properties of it, e.g. `CONSTANT_.setBlah(...)`?

Comment: I set a New Value